# Explanation of Insert Key in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, keyevent

I am trying to notify the user when some Keys are pressed. If `Caps`, `Num`, `Scroll` and `Insert` are pressed, the relative `BarStaticItem` (the application uses some devexpress controls) changes color to White.

```
void DxMainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.CapsLock)
    {

        if (e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyToggled(Key.CapsLock))
        {
            bCaps.Tag = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }
        else
        {
            bCaps.Tag = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
        } 
    }

    if (e.Key == Key.NumLock)
    {
        if (e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyToggled(Key.NumLock))
        {
            bNum.Tag = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }
        else
        {
            bNum.Tag = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
        } 
    }

    if (e.Key == Key.Scroll)
    {
        if (e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyToggled(Key.Scroll))
        {
            bScrl.Tag = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }
        else
        {
            bScrl.Tag = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
        } 
    }

    if (e.Key == Key.Insert)
    {
        if (e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyToggled(Key.Insert))
        {
            bIns.Tag = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }
        else
        {
            bIns.Tag = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
        } 
    }
}
```

Everything works fine but when i press `Insert` inside a `TextBox` it does not work. The weird thing is that in dispute of the other `KeyEvents` the event for `Insert` is like never happening (breakpoint does not break), even if the functionality works fine (overwrite text when pressed etc).

Can someone explain me why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Insert key is handled by the TextBox control, so that the event is not routed up the UI element tree.

You may however attach a handler for the `PreviewKeyDown` event instead of `KeyDown`:

```
<Window ... PreviewKeyDown="DxMainWindow_KeyDown">
```

Please refer to the [Routed Events Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) article on MSDN for more details.